# How To check if submit button has been clicked PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have a page that is submitting data to itself, and the code I have is working, but the problem is when I load my page this error `Notice: Undefined index: submitted` in is on the page when I get there. However, once I give it the data and click submit, the error goes away and everything else goes smoothly. Any idea how to get rid of this?

```
<form method="POST" action="contactInfo.php">
<center>
Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"/> 
<input type ="submit" name="submitted" value="Submit" /> <br />
<?php
$formSubmitted = $_POST['submitted'];
if ($formSubmitted)
{
  echo "Thank you for your information.";
} ?>
```

Comment: Check if it is a POST request before trying to grab the POST data from it.

Comment: use `if (isset($_POST['submitted']))`

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST['submitted']` doesn't exist yet until you submit the page. When visiting the page initially, it does not exist.

`$formSubmitted = isset($_POST['submitted']);`

Comment: Wow, easy fix, thanks!